# Get Google to ignore backlinks from a particular domain

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo

I just used a backlink scan tool to show me the backlinks to my site. I have found there are almost 90k backlinks. The problem is that about 95% of these are coming from the same domains and these are fake looking sites.

For example I have 55k backlinks coming from http://anethum.ca. this looks like a fake site and I don't know how these links even got there.

I don't want to get an Google penguin strike for unnatural backlinks so I want to just ignore them. Is it possible to tell Google to ignore all backlinks from a domain? This way I won't get a strike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is disavow these domains in Google Search Console (webmaster tools). You can also block any referral from these sites so that anyone that follows the link will get an error. 403 is traditional and often signals to Google that you disapprove of the link though this is not absolute.